# Memory error when applying logistf()

Tags: r, memory, logistf

I am trying to apply logistf() on a dataframe (dim:11359x139). All the variables are binary. I get the following message:
"Error in logistf.fit(x = x, y = y, weight = weight, offset = offset, firth,  : 
no memory available".
Even if I take into consideration only 20 rows and 139 predictors of the dataframe I get the same. Is it a hardware issue or my fault?

Comment: Try less predictors. You should have (much) more samples (rows) than variables to have anything meaningful. Otherwise I can tell you that no variable contributes anything to your model without running the code at all.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it another try with less predictors. Is there a way to estimate how much more samples than variables you need in order to get something meaningful?

Comment: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0962280218784726, this might be helpful